# Splitting string packagename with class

Tags: java

I don't know why this code doesn't work.

This is my code.

```
String value[] = pce.getPropertyName().toString().split(".");
```

the value of pce.getPropertyName is com.newbie.model.Names

when I debug it the size of value is 0.

Anyone encounter this problem?

Comment: do you really believe that anybody can understand all problem just a one line code statement?

Comment: Well, then it's not even executing it correctly. if the value of `getPropertyName` is "com.newbie.model.Names" then it would not be 0. somewhere else theres a bug

Comment: What kind of object is pce? (I'm going to guess PropertyChangeEvent but there is no way to be sure) What does getPropertyName() return?

Comment: It is really interesting how such question gets upvoted?

Comment: @mmc18 - It should just stay at '0' , it doesn't nec'y need to be negative, it can stay neutral ;-)

Comment: Sorry for not replying. My problem was already solved. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the dot character, since dot is a meta-character:

```
String value[] = pce.getPropertyName().toString().split("\\.");
```

Comment: Thanks bro @aquaraga I should wait for 10 minutes before I can accept this answer. thanks again

Answer (score 3):

`.` has a special meaning in regex-world (specifically, it matches *any character*), and recall that [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) does indeed take a regular expression as an argument. You want

```
String value[] = pce.getPropertyName().toString().split("\\.");
```

i.e. escape the `.`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dot or other characters with a special meaning in regexes to be a normal character, you have to escape it with a backslash. Since regexes in Java are normal Java strings, you need to escape the backslash itself, so you need two backslashes like `\\.`

[Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bs) for the same can be found here.

So, this is what you should do.

`String value[] = pce.getPropertyName().toString().split("\\.");`